# NSeviceBus 6 - How to inject IMessageSession using Autofac into a .Net Web API Controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, autofac, nservicebus

I'm running into a bit of a chicken and egg problem with using NServiceBus 6, Autofac and a .NET web api application. According to the the NSB documentation, [NSB 6 does not automatically inject IMessageSession into a controller](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/5to6/moving-away-from-ibus#dependency-injection).  When I do the endpoint configuration in Startup.cs, I need to give it a pre-built container, but then I also need to register the subsequently created endpoint.

Autofac complains that using `Builder.Update()` to modify the container is obsolete.  It works, but I wanted to get some feedback as to a better way to do this, if possible.

```
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();

        var container = builder.Build();
        httpConfig.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        var config = new EndpointConfiguration("....");
        config.SendFailedMessagesTo("Error");
        //......
        config.SendOnly();
        config.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>( customizations =>
                 {
                     customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(container);
                 });

        var endpointInstance =  Endpoint.Start(config).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // This is now needed to get IMessageSession injected into the controller
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();  
        builder.RegisterInstance(endpointInstance).As<IMessageSession>();

        // Autofac says Update is OBSOLETE and not to modify the 
        // container after it is built!
        builder.Update(container);
```

Comment: Why do you need to inject IMessageSession in the first place? If you explain what you want to achieve, we could come up with an alternative so you don't need to update the container once built.

Comment: It doesn't look like this code is quite what you're using since you have two variables named "config" in the same scope.

Comment: @HadiEskandari I need to be able to send messages from my web api controllers.  In NSB 5, I would have added an IBus property that would be automatically set up to be injected by NSB and used Bus.Send().

Comment: @TravisIllig Yes, it was meant to just capture what I was trying to do, not be a complete configuration.  I have fixed up the httpConfig in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda registrations to your advantage here.

First, let's say you have a static method that does your endpoint creation. It'll make it easier to show the example if so. It'd look like this:

```
public static IMessageSession CreateMessageSession(ILifetimeScope container)
{
  var config = new EndpointConfiguration("....");
  config.SendFailedMessagesTo("Error");
  //......
  config.SendOnly();
  config.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>( customizations =>
             {
                 customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(container);
             });

  return Endpoint.Start(config).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Note I switched to use an `ILifetimeScope` instead of the container.

Now you can do this:

```
builder.Register(ctx => CreateMessageSession(ctx.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()))
       .As<IMessageSession>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

By using `SingleInstance` the lifetime scope resolved in the lambda will effectively be the root container. Things will line up as needed.

I recognize you may need/want that `EndpointConfiguration` object elsewhere. You can still use lambdas but register a closure over the object. Change the static method to take in the endpoint configuration as well and...

```
var endpointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration("....");
builder.Register(ctx => CreateMessageSession(endpointConfig, ctx.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()))
       .As<IMessageSession>()
       .SingleInstance();
// Do further work with endpointConfig - lambda won't get called
// until you actually resolve IMessageSession so the closure is
// like a lazy bind.
```

Even if your requirements are more complex, I think lambdas and closures over objects like this are going to be your way around trying to update a built container.